# Include template is not showing content when page called?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to call `content.blade.php` for both ajax and url direct calling ! If I called as ajax , I don't want to include `master.blade` because it has jquery and many basic link ,it will cause duplicate file ! When I called as direct link in browser , I need to include `master.blade` . But the content page is not showing `(eg.This is content)` when I called as direct url in browser ,ajax call has no problem !! How can I solve this ?

Say test action,

```
public function test(Request $request) {
   return view("content",[ajax,$request->ajax()]);
}
```

master.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
@section('sidebar')
This is the master sidebar.
@show
<div class="container">
@yield('content')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

content.blade.php

```
@includeWhen(!$ajax,"master")
@section('content')
  This is content
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing because you're calling the `@section('content')` but you have no template that is yielding it.

You could make another layout without all the scripts that you don't want:

### ajax.blade.php

```
@yield('content')
```

And then in your content.blade.php, extend the `master.blade.php` when it's not ajax or extend the `ajax.blade.php` when it's ajax:

### content.blade.php

```
@extends($ajax ? 'ajax' : 'master')
@section('content')
    This is content
@endsection
```